# wait until player sends message - Java / Spigotmc

Tags: java, minecraft

I am creating minecraft plugin and I need the system to wait until player sends message (that message will be saved as a variable). But I can't figure out how to do that...

I tried to create loop function that would always check if that player sent message (once the player sends a message it would be removed from array or HashMap) and if not it would send player a title with message "type XYZ to chat" but everytime I run that function it causes extreme lag and after that server crash... Is there any different method?

My loop function:

```java
public boolean RequestMessage(String name, Player player) {
        String[] MessageArray = name.split("-");
        if(RPlayers.containsKey(player.getName())) {
            if (MessageArray[0].equals("edit")) {
                if (MessageArray[1].equals("join")) {
                    player.sendTitle(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA+"Edit Join message", ChatColor.GREEN+"left click"+ChatColor.GRAY+" to cancel", 0, 30, 0);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long) 5000);
                        RequestMessage(name, player);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

and I rum that with

```java
RPlayers.put(player.getName(), "edit-join-"+(1));
RequestMessage("edit-join-"+(1), player);
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with the Bukkit/Spigot API but I think handling [events](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference) are the proper way to run code upon detecting a player chat message.

Comment: Yeah... I know  the only thing Is I need the "request message" in exact while (once he clicks something in GUI) and during that while I need to send title to that player, that ends once he sends that message. I already have set up my "onChatMessage" function... I just had problems with that so I deleted that and im gona try again  but thanks a lot

Comment: I did it using different method! Thanks for your help